# Why did my Cisco router hang?

Tags: cisco, router, ios

We have a Cisco 1841 in our storage IDF that was originally running a 12.4(1) IP-BASE image; I wanted to upgrade to an advancedservicesk9-mz image, but the flash did not have enough space, so I deleted the running image.  Later I tried inserting a larger CF from a Catalyst4500, which crashed the 1841 router (now without a bootable image).

Using another 1800 series router, I loaded the 12.4(25g) advancedservicesk9 image and verified the image checksums.  I set the confreg to 0x2102 from rommon and booted the new image; however the 1841 now hangs indefinitely after printing the IOS export control banner.

I have tried four other images, all with the same results.  What is wrong with this router?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried loading images from a FAT16-formatted USB, but this didn't work either.

I also tried `tftpdnld` from rommon, but got a `get_mac_address(): Search T_IDPROM_MACADDR (0xc3) failed Illegal MAC address.` error and the file would not load.

Comment: Did you check the memory requirement of the images ?

Comment: yes, I have 192MB in the Cisco and all images require this much or less

Comment: Check the MD5 of the image against Cisco's website? Try going back to the IP-BASE image?

Comment: The IP-BASE image will not load either now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem wound up being a corrupted cookie in rommon... Cisco IOS uses a hidden cookie value to derive the mac-address and serial number for the chassis.  If the cookie is corruped, IOS cannot finish loading... all `ff` values below is obviously corrupted.

[This site](http://ers.msk.ru/cisco/priv.html) has more information about how the rommon cookie works; however, Cisco TAC says that changing the cookie is not supported on 1800 series routers and an RMA is the only real solution.

---

```
rommon 9 > cookie

cookie:
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
rommon 10 >
```